# Secret view, unlocked by server database

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm developing an application for students with some courses. I have some content that will be free and available to the general public but i wanted a section that only my 'real life' students would have access to like a Q&A inside the app.

My ideia was to have a database on a server with an email list which would allow access to the secret part of my app.

My questions are:

- Will apple allow this type of feature?
- If so, is this the best approach to unlock this feature?

Comment: If the app is just for *your* students (i.e. not just anybody can download it from the store) then its not a question of if apple will allow feature X or feature Y, it is a question of if Apple will allow even allow the app into the app store in the first place. Which they probably won't.

Comment: As I said in my question the app will have some content that will be free and available to the general public. Its just the Q&A which will be secret. Videos and documents will be available to everyone.

Comment: Then you should have said "..for students" and not "for my students" to make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Apple will allow this as long as you have some content for the general public.

What you are looking for is some kind of server backend.  Take a look at Parse.com  Great feature set.  You could probably stick with the free service level.  Handles logins and users simply.